# Use Table Export button to perform another function before exporting the Table

Tags: jquery, html, regex, excel

I am using Table Export to export the HTML table to an .xlsx file. The issue comes when my table has a character like "/" followed by a number. On the excel sheet it changes them to special characters.

[image: Excel]

Is there anyway I can avoid that.
If not I want to add space between the "/" and the number. And I want to do that by clicking on the "Export to xlsx" button which is created by tableexport.js. I want the click function to change that on the table and then export to excel.

Here is my code so far:

HTML

```
<table class="request-table" border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Downton /4bbey</td>
    <td>D/3xter</td>
    <td>/1Zombie</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Chuc/5</td>
    <td>Fr/1ng/e</td>
    <td>/Breaking /6ad</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
        $(".addSpace").each(function() {
                    var text = $(this).text();
                    $(this).text(text.replace(/\//g, '/ ')); 
            });

$(".request-table").tableExport({
        bootstrap: false,
        formats: [ "xlsx"]
});
```

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rashmee_p/o1t4tekx/12/)

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

The entityMap section in the tableexport.min.js is missing a semicolon

&#47 should have a semicolon at the end.

This will solve the issue of the "/"